# How to produce a simple text table

Tags: r, text, datatable

I have done the work to create a data frame that is the top 20 employers. So no need for grouping or sorting. It is already arranged in descending order. Sorry, if this is rudimentary but everything I find is more complex. What is the best package for creating a simple text table that would look this and have horizontal grid lines only. In other words, something that replicates exactly what is in the environment

```
    County     Emp Name    Emp Range
    Lander         X         100-249
    Lander         Y          50-99
```

Comment: What kind of format are you looking for? A .txt file, .doc, .tex, etc.?

Comment: For right now, a .txt file would work. Just trying to produce one correctly and then move on to more complex stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dat <- data.frame(matrix(c("County",
         "Emp Name",
         "Emp Range",
         "Lander",
         "X",
         "100-249",
         "Lander",
         "Y",
         "50-99"), nrow = 3, byrow = T))

write.table(dat, file = "my_table.txt", sep = "\t",
            row.names = F, col.names = F)
```

Once you got this, you can take a look at the `kable` package, it is also quite easy to use.